# I want to move some elements of an array to array's top

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array: *$content*.

It's keys are only numbers.
I want to check whether a value is a valid directory. If it is, I want to move the value to the top of the array preserving the key, or in other words, move the entire key and value. Is this possible?
Here is the code:

```
foreach ($content as $item){
    if(is_dir("path/$item")){
        # the code for values movement should go here
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like you want to sort your array. You probably want to google for `usort()`, so you can sort your array with your own custom sorting function, so that all directories are at the top and the rest at the bottom.

Comment: Yes! But I don't know how to do that. I can't seem to understand how usort() actually works.

Comment: Have you read the manual page and looked at the examples?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to create some sort of code, but it works only for two of directories.:    usort($content, function($b){return is_dir("$global_path/$b") ? -1 : 1;});

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by merging a temporary array into your $content array:

```
$temp = array($item => $content[$item]);
unset($content[$item]);
$content = $temp + $content;
```

Comment: This moves indeed the values to the top of array, but does not preserve the keys. I think I wasn't very specific about that.

Comment: you mean you always want to rewrite the first key?

Comment: i think this happens because you are having a numeric indexed array, not associative. Try using strings as your keys and it will preserve that key.

Answer (score 0):

You could split those arrays fist and then merge them again
So when it's a valid directory add to array1 and else add to array2